# Windows form closes after System.Threading.Timer elaples

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building an alarm clock application and using System.Threading.Timer. After the timer is elapsed I wanna show usercontrol to allow user to choose either to wake up or to snooze. After adding a new control or form in callback the form is just closing.

```
private void setTimerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            alarmDate = setAlarmDateTimePicker.Value - DateTime.Now;
            var alarmClock = new System.Threading.Timer(AlarmCallback, null, alarmDate, TimeSpan.Zero);
            addedAlarmTextBox.Text = setAlarmDateTimePicker.Text;
        }
        catch
        {}
        finally
        {
            setAlarmDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    private void AlarmCallback(object state)
    {
            this.Controls.Add(new AlarmBeepsForm());
    }
```

As far as I know, it has something with the threads, but I'm quite new to programming and I don't understand what's wrong.
How can I change the code to successfully add the control or should I use another type of timer?

Comment: The issue is Cross Thread Operation. You access the control created in main thread from a thread pool thread. You should use `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: [System.Threading.Timer remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0#remarks). The tip tells you about the different types of timers and you'll hopefully see that the one you've picked isn't appropriate

Comment: Wrong timer, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.  The one in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false`, you should call `Control.Invoke` to switch to the thread that created the control handle.

```
private void setTimerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      alarmDate = setAlarmDateTimePicker.Value - DateTime.Now;
      var alarmClock = new System.Threading.Timer(AlarmCallback, null, alarmDate, TimeSpan.Zero);
      addedAlarmTextBox.Text = setAlarmDateTimePicker.Text;
   }
   catch
   {}
   finally
   {
      setAlarmDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
private void AlarmCallback(object state)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Controls.Add(new AlarmBeepsForm()));
}
```